# Combobox dropdown not same size?

Tags: wpf

[image]

In my WPF application, I have a host window which dynamically holds usercontrols at runtime for doing the flip, fade etc. My user controls are forms with the controls like textbox, combobox etc. The dropdown's text size is not proportional to the size of the combobox. Is there any way to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `FontSize` of your `ComboBox` is different from the `FontSize` of your `ComboBoxItems`.

Try making both the same `FontSize` and see if that fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

How do you increase the size of the combobox? have you tried increasing the FontSize?

```
<ComboBox FontSize="16" />
```